# Hibernate HQL Query throwing Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

Please help me tosolve my problem-
If I am running the same query in sqlplus, it is working fine.

```
net.sf.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT [SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.SettlementCurrencyName = r.ContractCurrency THEN p.ContractNet WHEN s.SettlementCurrencyName = r.LocalCurrency THEN p.ContractNet/ta.LiquidationRate WHEN s.SettlementCurrencyName IS NULL THEN p.ContractNet/ta.LiquidationRate ELSE p.ContractNet/ta.LiquidationRate END)"PAID AMOUNT", COUNT(t.TX_IDENTIFIER) "PAID TXS" FROM com.uniteller.txcore.Payment p, com.uniteller.txcore.Transaction t, com.uniteller.txcore.TxAccounting ta, com.uniteller.txcore.Remittance r, com.uniteller.txcore.SellingAgentSettlement s WHERE t.isLRCTx = 1 AND t.SellingCompany = :lrcCode AND s.SettlementCurrencyName(+) = r.ContractCurrency AND s.Id.DestCurrencyName(+) = r.ContractCurrency AND s.Id.Code(+) = r.SellingAgent AND r.ContractCurrency = :contractCurrency AND p.PaidAccountDt > :lastPaidAcDt AND p.TxIdentifier = t.TxIdentifier AND p.TxIdentifier = r.TxIdentifier AND p.TxIdentifier = ta.TxIdentifier]
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.SelectParser.token(SelectParser.java:169)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:87)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.ClauseParser.end(ClauseParser.java:114)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.PreprocessingParser.end(PreprocessingParser.java:143)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:30)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.compile(QueryTranslator.java:149)
at net.sf.hibernate.hql.QueryTranslator.compile(QueryTranslator.java:138)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getQuery(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getQueries(SessionImpl.java:1572)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:1543)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:49)
at com.uniteller.tools.databroker.Main.main(Main.java:85)
```

Comment: its hard to debug so long query. try to remove parts one by one and see what is the part that cause the failure. than fix the question with small query .

Comment: The community can help you better, if you post some code rather than a long generated hql. The problem can be in your logic/code rather than the hql.

Comment: @Satadru Biswas The exception message is fairly clear ", expected in SELECT" -  I think the problem lies with the HQL

Comment: the exception is clear. And the message is that something is missing in the hql. The hql is generated by the code. So, code is what we need to see to actually help the OP. The answers currently are vague. If the exact code cannot be shown, then the OP should post some example code illustrating a similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem can be in that you try to execute your query as HQL query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(...);
```

But as I see your query is not HQL, thats why you should execute it as native sql query:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(...);
```

Comment: :lrcCode - this is HQL, not SQL

Answer (score 0):

)"PAID AMOUNT" needs a space between ) and "